# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED?Can any tell me what is the error in my AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm getting the below error while i'm trying to run the code.
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Please can any one help me to sort out this error.

Attached is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourevent.mobilevideoinvitation" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.yourevent.mobilevideoinvitation.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.yourevent.mobilevideoinvitation.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"         />

<application
    android:name=".ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".StaggeredGridActivityFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.STAGGEREDGRIDACTIVITYFRAGMENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".EnterEventDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ENTEREVENTDETAILS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StaggeredGridActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.STAGGEREDGRIDACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowScript"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".StaggeredGridActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SHOWSCRIPT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidVideoCapture"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".ShowScript"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANDROIDVIDEOCAPTURE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BackgroundScore"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".AndroidVideoCapture"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BACKGROUNDSCORE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Invite"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".BackgroundScore"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INVITE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShareScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".BackgroundScore"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SHARESCREEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
            -->
                <category android:name="com.yourevent.mobilevideoinvitation" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing that causes such error:

> ```
> <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" />
> ```

`meta-data` requires an `android:value` or `android:resource` attribute.

There can be additional reasons for the same error. You can look at the [`PackageParser` source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java)
 to learn under which conditions the error is produced.